# Excel - get data between two sheets by find number and lookup data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, spreadsheet

I have sheet Result and want to get data from sheet Source.
Pls help to show me how can I get data as image following.

[image]

Tks you so much !

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: I use MS Office Standard 2016, so can we have formula to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First option:**

Un-merge the cell in source sheet and instead of "Detail", type meaningful column names to B1 to F1.

Then select your data and create a pivot table (pls do some google if you need to).

Play with pivot table until you reach the view you want (it is possible to get the same view as the result sheet you shared.)

**Second option as you requested:**

Insert a new column after column A in your source (between abs and roma).

Type this formula in this new column: =A2&H2.

Then type this formula in Result sheet B2: =Vlookup($A2&"2";Source!$B$2:$G$13;3;false)

Copy this to other cells.  Do not forget to update parameters for other cells.

Comment: Can you have other solution to write formula, for example find from column G =  2 or 4 and vlookup data ?

Comment: Added formula into my answer.  You will get incorrect result for cells other than B2 in result sheet.  Analyze the vlookup function in these cells and try to get them fixed pls.